# SQSQL Get parent if child is modified

Tags: salesforce, sosql

In Salesforce I have tables for contracts and for included services.
With the REST API I want to fetch all contract which are modified in the last two days or if one of their included services is modified in the last two days.

I can get contract with included services using sub select like

```
SELECT LastModifiedDate, Id, Name
       (SELECT  LastModifiedDate, Id, Name, 
        FROM Contract__c.Included_Services__r 
        WHERE LastModifiedDate > 2023-08-17T00:00:00Z) 
FROM Contract__c 
WHERE LastModifiedDate > 2023-08-17T00:00:00Z
```

But now I need to check if count of included services is not null

Is this possible or must I go the revers way and select included services and "Join" the contracts (Which would last in much more data to retrieve) ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can do it with 1 "top-down" query, this throws the "Semi join sub-selects are not allowed with the 'OR' operator" error.

```soql
SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contacts WHERE LastModifiedDate = THIS_MONTH)
FROM Account
WHERE LastModifiedDate = THIS_MONTH OR Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE LastModifiedDate = THIS_MONTH)
LIMIT 10
```

You could prepare the data a bit to help you... For example what's the relation between contract and service exactly? If it's Master-Detail and there are rollups, cross-object workflows, flows, process builder... - on update of Service they'd be updating the Contract too so the last mod date would change automatically. Or write a simple `after insert, after update` trigger that "touches" the Contract without changing any fields, just to change the last modified date?

Failing that...

You'll have to do it "bottom-up" (start from Service and join to Contract)

```
SELECT Id, LastName, LastModifiedDate, Account.Id, Account.Name, Account.LastModifiedDate
FROM Contact WHERE LastModifiedDate = THIS_MONTH OR Account.LastModifiedDate = THIS_MONTH
ORDER BY Account.Name, LastName
LIMIT 10
```

Or split it into 2 queries

```
SELECT Id
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE LastModifiedDate = THIS_MONTH)
```

and then

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts)
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN :idsFrom1stQuery OR LastModifiedDate = THIS_MONTH
```

It's more network traffic, API calls and if there were lots of updates you may hit the 100K characters limit of query length...

Comment: Thx, that are exact my thoughts, I just wanted to verify that I do not oversee something more simple